# KafkaJS - Find offset most efficient way

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

(Complete beginner when it comes to kafka and kafkajs so i'm sorry if this is silly question)

I have a problem where we have a topic that retains 48hrs of data (millions of records); And i'm wondering the best way to get from this topic the last "20 minutes" of data and then also stream new messages.

Each message in this topic is JSON and has a timestamp in UNIX milliseconds since epoch (UTC).

Performance is obviously an issue here

Answer (score 1):

There is a facility in the Java client to seek to offsets by *timestamp*.
There is a [PR](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/pull/604) in KafkaJS for this, it doesn't *seem* to be verified and merged though.

I suppose `node-rdkafka` has it. An example is below ([reference](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/issues/336#issuecomment-384774377))

```
consumer.offsetsForTimes(
    [ {topic: 'hi', partition: 0, offset: Date.now() - (20*60*1000) } ],
    timeout,
    console.log
);
```

When you get the offsets, you can seek to them and start reading.